# Bubblesort 3 arrays in vba

Tags: arrays, vba, sorting, solidworks

I'm having a bit of an issue trying to sort 3 different arrays and then have them output as one array at the end of the sort. I am using a standard bubblesort and am able to sort each array individually but sadly have been unable to figure out how to sort them all at once. 
This is my sort sub:

```
Sub BubbleSort(list() As Note)

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim Temp As Note
Dim last As Long
last = UBound(list)
For i = 0 To last - 1
    For j = i + 1 To last
        If Val(list(i).TagName) < Val(list(j).TagName) Then
            Set Temp = list(j)
            Set list(j) = list(i)
            Set list(i) = Temp
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

My three arrays are notex, notey, and notes.
They all look basically the same as below:

```
Set swFirstNote = swView.GetFirstNote
    Set swNote = swView.GetFirstNote
    ReDim notex(notesTotalCounter)
    i = 0
    While Not swNote Is Nothing

        If swNote.GetText Like "`*" Then
            Set notex(i) = swNote
            i = i + 1
            Set swAnno = swNote.GetAnnotation

            loc = swAnno.GetPosition
            Dim u As Double
            u = loc(0)

            swNote.TagName = u
        End If
        Set swNote = swNote.GetNext

    Wend
```

This is in Solidworks VBA by the way.

Edit:
I need to sort notex then notey then notes in that order

Comment: My understanding is you want one sorted array containing the elements of the three original arrays.  That being the case, why don't you combine all three arrays into a single array and then sort the combined array?

Comment: I don't have a problem with that, but Im not sure how to then sort the array after it is created. I am currently using the .TagName extension from the solidworks API to pass the information to the bubblesort, and .TagName, to my knowledge, cannot be used with an array. Arrays are not really my strong suit sadly.